# How to get the selected row items in ListView

Tags: vb.net, winforms

This is my ListView, Column 1 for ID and Column 2 for Notes

[image]

I have a Multi-Line textbox and a Button Like this

[image]

I want to load the selected note on the textbox when the button is clicked.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Do you want the load the contents of the ListView item into the textbox, or the contents of the textbox into the ListView item?

Comment: @Cody - Contents of ListView item into text-box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something similar to this (you'll have to tweak it for your setup)

```
If listView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    textBox.Text = listView.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
End If
```

if you don't like the idea of using column index and if you have your columns setup right then you should be able to do `.SubItems("ID").Text`

Answer (score 0):

the following may work

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems()
        TextBox1.AppendText(item.Text & ":" & item.SubItems(1).Text & Environment.NewLine)
Next
```